# Adding "thoughts on something" to the "metadata" of a fountain screenplay

Tags: screenwriting, scriptwriting

I'm using [fountain syntax](https://fountain.io) for my screenplays and currently, I'm having trouble deciding, where to put my thoughts on something (let's say, worldbuilding) in the screenplay. Of course, it can't be anywhere where it would be printed. I'm aware of the [synopses syntax](https://fountain.io/syntax#section-sections) (`=`) as well as the [title page](https://fountain.io/syntax#section-titlepage) fountain offers for key-value pairs. So, which of the options do you feel, is more intuitive to you?

**Option 1: Synopses**

```
Title: Example screenplay

= World building notes: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
= Dramaturgical notes: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

====

INT. A room -- DAY
```

**Option 2: Title page**

```
Title: Example screenplay
World building notes:
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
Dramaturgical notes:
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

====

INT. A room -- DAY
```

Comment: As I understand it, there shouldn't be any notes or annotations in a screenplay (or any other manuscript, for that matter). Your work notes should reside outside the screenplay, either in a different file or in the comment option of your writing software.  –– If you actually need to make annotations (such as sources for citations that are required for legal reasons), you should insert them as foot- or endnotes or in the margin of the script.

Comment: I thought about foot- or endnotes, however, since they are not explicitly part of the fountain standard (just the markdown one), I refrained from using them. But yeah, your remark about them even being in the screenplay, unfortunately makes sense ^^

Comment: Such things should go in your blog, not your screenplay. If you have a message use email.

Comment: Blog? Email? How are you organized? oO

Answer (score 1):

> where to put my thoughts on something (let's say, worldbuilding) in
> the screenplay. Of course, it can't be anywhere where it would be
> printed.

Fountain has at least 2 ways add text that are for **author's notes** that won't appear in the final formatting.

**Notes** is probably what you're looking for. Use double-square brackets to section text that is an *annotation to yourself*. It is designed to transfer into annotation formatting in other software.

[[ *some text* ]]

Notes work in-line, or on a separate line, but typically not paragraphs of prose. This is not communication text, this is the screenwriter's equivalent of a Post-it™.

**Boneyard** is similar to code scripting, where a large chunk of text is commented out by opening and closing syntax:

/* *some text* */

or

/*
*some text*
*/

You could create your own formatting within boneyard text, to make it easier to see.

Notes and boneyard text will be omitted when Fountain is formatted by compatible software but obviously this text should be scrubbed from any draft intended for anyone else to read, since it isn't actually 'hidden' in the text file at all.

---

As mentioned in the comments, in your final screenplay any descriptive text that indicates non-dialog storytelling is formatted as **action**.

If the scene needs to communicate worldbuilding, it is told through the action of characters and camera. It might be best policy to re-work any 'infodump' text into on-screen action (AKA 'character business') as early in the screenwriting process as possible.

Comment: Yeah, the notes are secondarily meant for import purposes. I need something that is standard enough to be parsed properly but can be used in a way that the import can store these information in a customized way if needed. And of course, this information would be scrubbed before not later than the creation of the shooting script. So this functionality is meant for spec scripts only.